# ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, sqlplus, tnsnames

I am trying to connect to an oracle database using oracle sqlplus instant client using tnsnames.ora. But getting this error: ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified.

I have following environmental value set up :

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH,TNS_ADMIN, ORACLE_HOME
```

The location of sqlplus is added to the PATH Variable. My instantclient10_2 deploying is located at ~/Library/oracle direcoty. The oracle folder has all the access to the user.

I am able to connect with TNS using oracle SqlDeveloper. Please help me resolve this issue.

OS Version:- Mac OS X 10.7.2 (Lion)

Comment: Oracle SQLDeveloper comes with its own JDBC client... that has nothing to do with the instant client you installed... please provide more information...

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the `tnsnames.ora`, and the way you are starting sqlplus.

Comment: Following are the sample tns entry in my tnsnames.ora:-VPN2TEST=
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=
             (ADDRESS=(HOST=${host1})(PORT=1699)(PROTOCOL=TCP))
             (ADDRESS=(HOST=${host2})(PORT=1699)(PROTOCOL=TCP)))
             (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=vpn2test.fiberlink.com)))   -Using following commands to connect with sqlplus                     >sqlplus user/passwd@vpn2test

Comment: I had a similar issue and solved adding a sqlnet.ora to my oracle (in my case 12.1) with the following contents: NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (TNSNAMES). In my environment, it's located at /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/network/admin/sqlnet.ora

Answer (score 2):

```
set ORACLE_SID=YOUR_SID_IN_tnsnames.ora
export ORACLE_SID
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the 'oracle sqlplus instant client' is simply sqlplus.exe

I recently fixed this problem by setting the Oracle Service ID or SID into the environment.

You can test this by issuing the commands:

```
Set ORACLE_SID=VPN2TEST
```

and reissuing your sqlplus.exe connection command.
If this works, and you want to make it permanant, (assuming windown7 or 2k8 server or greater), type:

```
setx /m ORACLE_SID VPN2TEST
```

This command will set the environment variable to survive a reboot, and will be available to all users of the machine.

Comment: I am trying to setup on MacOSX lion. There is no exe support.